# NodeJS (gettting error notes.push is not a function)

Tags: node.js

When I run this code I get push is not a function. I have gone over the code so many times and can't figure out where I went wrong. i have also read many of post and I still can't figure it out. I am new to programming and could use the help.

```
const fs= require('fs')

const getNotes = function() {
    return 'This just returns get notes'
```

enter code here
    };

```
const addNote  = function (title, body) {
    const notes = loadNotes()
    
    notes.push({
        title: title,
        boby: body
    })
    saveNotes(notes)
    
};

const saveNotes = function (notes) {
    const dataJSON = JSON.stringify(notes)
    fs.writeFileSync('notes.json',dataJSON)
}

// Code below loads the notes. Above, addNote adds the note.
const loadNotes = function () {

    try {
        const dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync('notes.json')
        const dataJSON= dataBuffer.toString()
        return JSON.parse(dataJSON)
    } catch (error) {
        return('Note such file')
    }
    
    
}

module.exports ={
    getNotes: getNotes,
    addNote: addNote
}
```

Comment: The problem is in the `notes.json`, if you share that here we could tell you what's wrong with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have this:

```
const notes = loadNotes()

notes.push({
    title: title,
    boby: body
});
```

If you're getting an error that `notes.push is not a function`, then that is because `loadNotes()` is not return an array.  That could be for a couple reasons:

1. `JSON.parse(dataJson)` successfully parses your json, but its top level object is not an array.
2. `JSON.parse(dataJson)` throws and you end up returning a string instead of an array.

You can fairly easily diagnose this by adding a `console.log()` statement like this:

```
const notes = loadNotes();
console.log(notes);           // see what this shows
notes.push({
    title: title,
    boby: body
});
```

FYI, returning a string from`loadNotes()`as an error really doesn't make much sense unless you're going to check for a string after calling that function.  IMO, it would make more sense to either return `null` for an error or just let it throw.  Both would be simpler and easier to check after calling `loadNotes()`.

And, in either case, you must check for an error return value after calling `loadNotes()` unless you want `loadNotes()` to throw upon error like it is.